# Security of traditional ORAMs if write accesses are revealed

Tags: secure-storage

I was reading about path ORAM, and I have few questions

1. I was wondering if an adversary knows all write accesses will be performed and has a view of the tree of which path being accessed. Can he infer anything about the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adversary will not be able to distinguish between that access pattern and any other with the same volume and timing.